# do-release-upgrade results in error: APT / GLib-Critical / apstreamcli / libappstream

Tags: apt, upgrade, 17.10, do-release-upgrade, appstream

i am currently trying to do-release-upgrade an Ubuntu 17.10 install to 18.04.6 LTS via 'sudo do-release-upgrade'. Sadly, the process does not finish, as it return the following very quickly:

```
(appstreamcli:26495): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:26495): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:26495): GLib-ERROR **: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Fehler während der Aktualisierung

Bei der Aktualisierung trat ein Problem auf. Dies ist häufig auf
Netzwerkprobleme zurückzuführen. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre
Netzwerkverbindung und versuchen Sie es erneut.

E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if
/usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli;
then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi', E:Sub-process
returned an error code
```

Having stumbled upon similar questions, i tried to reinstall and even purge appstreamcli and libappstream4, however to no avail. Interestingly, both `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` work without problems (although no more upgrades can be found due to the end-of-support I guess).

Here is also the output from

```
sudo apt-show-versions appstream
```

```
appstream:amd64 not installed
appstream:i386 not installed
```

and

```
sudo apt-show-versions libappstream4
```

```
libappstream4:amd64/artful 0.11.3-1 uptodate
libappstream4:i386 not installed
```

Happy to here your thoughts on how to tackle this - thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my login screen, prompting me to `do-release-upgrade` [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5i5R.png)

Comment: Are you sure you've applied all upgrades & security fixes to your system?  You haven't mentioned the command normally required prior to attempts to run [Ubuntu release upgrader tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader), how on a 17.10 system I'd not even attempt to *release-upgrade* (esp. if desktop system), and just re-install (*unclean install if necessary; as it won't touch your user files, and manually installed packages will be auto-reinstalled if available for new release in official Ubuntu repositories*)

Comment: Install a supported release after backing up your personal files.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I applied all upgrades & security fixes, such that do-release-upgrade should be possible, e.g. following https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/upgrade-introduction - however the error with appstream persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Old Ubuntu 17.10 installation with the same exact error. I read in various articles that appstreamcli is not needed for the upgrade and ultimately i used the solution suggested in

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464445/problem-with-appstreamcli-when-running-apt-update

to simply go to to  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream and comment out the APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success function with sudo permissions. During the Upgrade appstreamcli was updated and the change i made to the 50appstream file was noticed and offered to be replaced with a new one which i accepted. The Upgrade went trough without problems and im now on 18.04.6 LTS :)
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! A reboot after the edit was missing for me to fix the issue!